# ¿Se escribe Eximición o Eximisión?

Tags: gramática

Tengo una duda sobre la palabra `Eximición`, o si se escribiera `Eximisión`.

Ya que ambas palabras no me son reconocidas por el navegador, y las considera que están escritas incorrectamente, o ¿está mal conjugada?

Ejemplo:

```
Solicito eximición del examen
```

> Con `s` o `c`, se subraya la palabra como incorrecta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una palabra que no había oído en mi vida, no aparece en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/eximici%C3%B3n?m=form) pero si en el diccionario de americanismos:

> **[eximición](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=eximici%C3%B3n)**.
>   **I.  1.**    f. *Bo, Ch, Ar*. Exención de una carga, obligación o culpa. prest;
>   cult → esm.

Es un sustantivo creado a partir del verbo *eximir* con el sufijo [-ción](https://dle.rae.es/-ci%C3%B3n) por lo tanto se escribe con *c*.

Comment: Es curioso que las usamos en distintas combinaciones léxicas, por ejemplo *eximición de prisión* (para alguien que queda exento de ir a prisión) pero *exención impositiva* (para quien no está obligado a pagar un impuesto).

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer en Argentina se usa con "s", ejemplos :EXIMISIÓN EN IMPUESTO DE SELLOS, EXIMISIÓN AGROPECUARIA IMPUESTO INMOBILIARIO. Certificado que exime del pago del impuesto inmobiliario a titular ... , EXIMISIÓN CURSO DE INGRESO Los estudiantes que ya posean un título universitario ..., Eximisión pago del arancel ... ,Ley de eximisión transitoria de tributos ..., ETC.

Comment: NO es correcto escribir "eximiSión". Debe escribirse: "eximiCión". https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/601749456254566400

Comment: [¿Seguro?](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/servicio/presentar-solicitud-de-eximicion) Recuerda que tenemos errores de ortografía. Si lo viste es probable que haya sido escrito con desconocimiento.